# What is the definition of power down in HBM memory?

Tags: sdram, dram

Reading the datasheets, it says data still needs to be maintained during power down and thus controller can't keep a channel in power down longer than the defined refresh requirement of the DRAM.

Which portion of the DRAM channel is disabled during power down and how much power is saved?

Best.

Comment: Link datasheets and where this appears.

Comment: Probably not appropriate to upload it. Hope people familiar with DRAM or HBM could understand the question and provide help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The power down means the power consumption is lower. There are two different ways of idling the DRAM. One is standing by (standby mode), and the other is powering down (power down mode). In either case, DRAM is doing nothing except that it keeps monitoring the commands. But that duty is a little different between when the DRAM is in the standby mode vs. when it is in the power down mode.

1. Standby mode

Any valid command can come anytime (i.e. next cycle), and if it happens then the DRAM should react right away. To do this, it should keep running every piece of the logic (i.e. command/address input receivers [all pins], command decoder, nest clocks, etc.) as if it was running busy.

2. Power down mode

The only command that can come while the DRAM is in the power down mode is the power down exit command, whereas any command could come while the DRAM was in a standby mode. Because there's only 1 case, it's possible to define the command truth table so that the DRAM needs to watch only 1 pin instead of all the command and address pins. Actually they (JEDEC) did so. If you look at any DRAM spec, the specs were defined so that it's enough for DRAM to keep just one input receiver alive to catch the power down exit event.

This saves some (but not a lot) power, as it can shut down the rest of command and address input buffers and internal capturing delay lines, and large portion of the nest clock, because the DRAM spec also allows some wake up time - i.e. it's not allowed to issue valid commands right after the power down exit.

The bottom line is that the power down doesn't save the active powers but it can save good amount of standby powers.